# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null in react render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, websocket

I'm trying to implement web sockets in my react frontend to stream some frames to it with canvas.

First the code was working fine and I could receive the data very well ... but when I needed to add a function call from the parent component, I got an error:

> videoSocket.js:51 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null

This is the code :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./canvas.css";

function b64toBlob(dataURI) {
  var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(",")[0]);

  var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
  var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);

  for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
    ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return new Blob([ab], { type: "image/jpeg" });
} /*
    ws.onmessage = function(event) {
        
        var img=document.getElementById("video_frames");
        var urlObject = URL.createObjectURL(event.data);
        img.src = urlObject;
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }*/

class VideoSocket extends Component {
  state = {
    websocket: null,
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + props.link);
    this.state = {
      websocket: ws,
    };
  }

  render() {
    const self = this;
    this.state.websocket.onmessage = function (event) {
      var js = JSON.parse(atob(event.data.split(",")[0]));

      var data = b64toBlob(js["data"]);
      var personinfo = { infos: js["infos"] };
      console.log(self.props);
      self.props.setdata(personinfo);

      var urlObject = URL.createObjectURL(data);

      var canvas = document.getElementById("tools_sketch");
      /*
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth; // equals window dimension
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;*/
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      var image = new Image();
      image.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(
          image,
          0,
          0,
          image.width,
          image.height, // source rectangle
          0,
          0,
          canvas.width,
          canvas.height
        );
      };

      image.src = urlObject;
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <canvas
          id="tools_sketch"
          width={this.props.width}
          height={this.props.height}
        >
          Sorry, your browser doesn't support the &lt;canvas&gt; element.
        </canvas>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default VideoSocket;
```

When I remove

```
self.props.setdata(personinfo);
```

it works fine but when I add it no matter what I tried it's not working .

I tried to add the function onmessage to componentdidmount like below but I get the same error.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./canvas.css";

function b64toBlob(dataURI) {
  var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(",")[0]);

  var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
  var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);

  for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
    ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return new Blob([ab], { type: "image/jpeg" });
} /*
    ws.onmessage = function(event) {
        
        var img=document.getElementById("video_frames");
        var urlObject = URL.createObjectURL(event.data);
        img.src = urlObject;
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }*/

class VideoSocket extends Component {
  state = {
    websocket: null,
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + props.link);
    this.state = {
      websocket: ws,
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const self = this;
    this.state.websocket.onmessage = function (event) {
      var js = JSON.parse(atob(event.data.split(",")[0]));

      var data = b64toBlob(js["data"]);
      var personinfo = { infos: js["infos"] };
      console.log(self.props);
      self.props.setdata(personinfo);

      var urlObject = URL.createObjectURL(data);

      var canvas = document.getElementById("tools_sketch");
      /*
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth; // equals window dimension
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;*/
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      var image = new Image();
      image.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(
          image,
          0,
          0,
          image.width,
          image.height, // source rectangle
          0,
          0,
          canvas.width,
          canvas.height
        );
      };

      image.src = urlObject;
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <canvas
          id="tools_sketch"
          width={this.props.width}
          height={this.props.height}
        >
          Sorry, your browser doesn't support the &lt;canvas&gt; element.
        </canvas>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default VideoSocket;
```

This is the server side code in python :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random
import websockets
import asyncio
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
import json 
import base64


#!/usr/bin/env python

# WS server that sends messages at random intervals


class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture('video2.mp4')

    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()

    def get_frame(self):
        while True:
            ret, image = self.video.read()
            ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
            base6 = base64.b64encode(jpeg.tobytes())
            yield base6.decode('utf-8')


def gen(camera):


    while True:
        image = next(camera.get_frame())

        yield(image)


async def time(websocket, path):
    camera = VideoCamera()
    i = 0
    while True:
        i = i+1
        data = next(gen(camera))
        js = {'data': data, "infos": [
            {'id': 1, 'name': 'name1'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'name2'}]}

        res_bytes = json.dumps(js).encode('utf-8')
        base6 = base64.b64encode(res_bytes)
        message = base6.decode('utf-8')

        await websocket.send(message)


start_server = websockets.serve(time, "127.0.0.1", 5678)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

**Edit** : the parent component code :

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";

import "antd/dist/antd.css";

import VideoSocket from "../components/videoSocket";
import MyTable from "../components/table";
class Home extends Component {
  state = { personinfo: {} };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let links = {
      1: "127.0.0.1:5678",
      2: "127.0.0.1:5679",
      3: "127.0.0.1:5680",
      4: "127.0.0.1:5681",
    };
    const CameraId = props.match.params.cameraId;
    console.log(CameraId);
    let link = links[CameraId];
    if (link == null) {
      link = "127.0.0.1:5678";
    }
    let curent = link;
    this.state = {
      links: links,
      curent: curent,
    };
    console.log(link);
  }
  setData = (personinfo) => {
    this.setState({
      personinfo: personinfo,
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className=".container-fluid overflow-auto" width="100%">
        <div></div>
        <VideoSocket
          className=""
          width={(window.innerWidth * 75) / 100}
          height="400px"
          link={this.state.curent}
          setdata={this.setData}
          key="1"
        ></VideoSocket>
        <MyTable personinfo={this.state.personinfo}></MyTable>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

**Edit**: I tried to add

```
shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }
```

to the component `videosocket` but it still do the same problem

Comment: i think i know the problem but not the answer , the problem i that th the function setdata change the state of the parent component so the parent reload with all the children  ,and when the component reload the script will still be running in the background and when the script execute   `var canvas = document.getElementById("tools_sketch"); ` it will return null because the component didn't load yet ....

Comment: so is there a way to prevent this component from reloading because i dont really need to change the state of the parent component i only need to change another child of that parent (the table ) "i added the code of the parent component )